# How should a Dist::Zilla plugin give feedback to the user?

Tags: perl, logging, user-feedback, dist-zilla

I have a couple of Dist::Zilla plugins that I wrote when I was very new to Moose and to Dist::Zilla both, and I'm currently trying to update them to make them a bit more robust, and less error-prone.

One thing I would like to do is to give the user feedback if I detect that they have given me contradictory or impossible instructions. Things like:

```
[ MyPlugin ]
include = all
exclude = all
```

Dist::Zilla does appear to have an (undocumented) internal logging system which I originally hooked into when I wrote my plugins, but which no longer seems to work (probably due to internal changes). So, how should I give the user feedback these days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Meant to put this in the comment but hit length limit).

Caveat: I've only written a couple of small dzil plugins myself, and am not very familiar with its internals.

dzil uses Log::Dispatchouli, which is also written by rjbs. Log::Dispatchouli is used by several other projects (including projects started by people other than rjbs), so it's not exactly an internal dzil logging system.

From what I understand, Log::Dispatchouli only has two logging levels, normal and debug. Debug logs are not normally seen in output; you have to enable debugging first. Normal (and debug) logs can be muted if you enable muting.

To enable debugging in dzil, add a -v command-line switch. This does not seem to be documented in 'dzil help' nor 'dzil help COMMAND'. But rjbs [blogged about it](http://rjbs.manxome.org/rubric/entry/1824).

Now to produce logs inside the dzil plugins, you just call $self->log(...) or $self->log_debug(...). The second one will be seen only if user passes -v option.

Comment: Also a confession: For some plugins I write, I also mix in Log::Any and use it to log instead of Log::Dispatchouli. I like having extra levels like 'trace', 'debug', 'info' as well as the sprintf-like capability of Log::Any.

Comment: I've noticed that Log::Dispatchouli has 8 or so levels of log output, but most seem disabled within dzil.